# How to create a Lambda function using AWS SDK for Java 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

How do one create a Lambda function using AWS SDK for Java 2.0? Usinx SDK 1.x, I can do so using the following:

```
public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
System.out.println("do stuff");
return "success";
}
```

Using java SDK 2.x, I can't seem to find the equivalent dependencies for S3Event and Context object? I would really appreciate if someone could point me to examples. Or should I just stick to using SDK 1.x if 2.x is not mature enough for handling lambda?

Comment: Did you found any way handle lambda function request with SDK 2.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`S3Event` is part of the [AWS Lambda Java Events](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events) library where `Context` is part of the [AWS Lambda Java Core](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-core).  When you include the events library you do pull in the 1.x Java SDK.  However, if you use the [Java Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html) version of the Lambda handler you can remove the dependency to the events library and thus remove your need for the 1.x SDK.  Your code would look something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;


public class S3EventLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {

        try {
            List<String> keys = JsonPath.read(inputStream, "$.Records[*].s3.object.key");

            for( String nextKey: keys )
                System.out.println(nextKey);
        }
        catch( IOException ioe ) {
            context.getLogger().log("caught IOException reading input stream");
        }
    }
}
```

then you can read the JSON that is in the S3Event yourself.  In effect, you're doing the serialization of the S3Event in your code instead of having the Amazon library do it.

Obviously the biggest downside is that you have to serialize the event yourself.  An example S3 event in JSON can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-s3-put).

The above example uses [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to pull out, in this case, the keys from the event.  You'll be amazed how much smaller your Lambda code is after you remove the Lambda Events library.

**Edit - September 2022**

I know it's not clear sometimes but the [AWS Lambda Core Library for Java](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-core) **does not have a version 2** - even 4 years after this post.  The Lambda Core library defines things like [Context](https://javadoc.io/static/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core/1.2.1/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/Context.html) and [RequestStreamHandler](https://javadoc.io/static/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core/1.2.1/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/RequestStreamHandler.html) as shown in my code above.  As of this writing, there are **still** 3 libraries that can be used for writing the **server** side of a Lambda in Java and they are all **still in the `com.amazonaws` package**.  These are not the libraries for accessing, as a client, the rest of AWS for which there are the V2 (in the `software.amazon` package) libraries.  The answer to the OP's question is still the same - a V2 library for writing the server side of a Lambda in Java does not exist.  Interacting, as a client, with the rest of the AWS environments - sure, there has been a V2 for quite a while. But not the "server" side of a Lambda.

The [AWS Lambda Java Events](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events) library is now on V3 and yet it still uses the `com.amazonaws` package.  For reference, I would write the code above without using a `RequestStreamHandler` as the events library is much lighter than it was 4 years ago but that doesn't change the package name.

Comment: It means there is no library to use S3Event in java SDK 2.x.

Comment: This doesn't use 2.0 code. Perhaps an early version? 2.0 packages start with "software.amazon.awssdk..."

Comment: @danorton - there isn't a 2.0 Java Lambda Core library yet.

Comment: @stdunbar The question was in the context of 2.0 SDK, but as OP accepted 1.x answer, I guess that's that.

Comment: That is not SDKV2, it is an SDKV1 example, and has yet been accepted.

Comment: Recently I started writing the code for lambda using V2 Java SDK and still the same, does it mean that we need to add SDK v2 Library and V1 library together to work with lambda?

Comment: @AbhishekVerma - the answer is still the same.  The [AWS Lambda Java Libs Core](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/main/aws-lambda-java-core) is still at 1.2.2.  That allows you to build the Lambda.  To interact with other AWS services, use the [AWS SDK for Java v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html).  On the SDK side you only need one version.